# How to create AWS instance snapshot - multiple volumes at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot

Let's say I have a AWS EC2 instances that have 3 volumes , how to I create a snapshot for the overall instances from AWS console includes all 3 volumes at the same time instead of doing volumes one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to simultaneously create 3 snapshots for 3 volumes using the AWS Management Console. You must create the snapshots one-by-one.

Your best bet is to create a script or use a snapshot service to do it for you.

Comment: Can you give me example of script and where to run it under AWS management console ? Cheers. Gob

Comment: There are many if you Google for it. One example is here http://www.cloudar.be/awsblog/automating-snapshotsbackups-of-ec2-ebs-volumes/ but most are linux based and you need to keep an instance running to run the scripts. You cannot run scripts in the management console.

Comment: But my AWS instance is windows based, does that mean I am back to manual operation again ?

Comment: No. You just need to be able to run your script. Either you create and/or find a Windows script (such as a powershell script), or you launch a Linux instance and run a Linux script.

Comment: You can use "aws ec2 create-snapshot" using the AWS Command Line Interface. Works in Windows, too.

Comment: That command will only create a single snapshot. So you need to either run it manually for each volume or run a script to call it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a snapshot/image for the overall instances which have multiple EBS volume from AWS console.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate the snapshot steps for the overall instance ?